# Close bootstrap modal automatically when a video inside modal body stops playing

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am using video.js to load a video inside a bootstrap modal. I need a modal to shutdown when a video is completed.

Answer (score 1):

Use video.js's `ended` event and run `.modal('hide')` on its callback, like this:

```
videojs('some-video').ready(function(){
  this.on('ended', function(){
      $('#modal').modal('hide');
  });
});
```